# Adding namespace to phpass (or any class)

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, phpass

I am using http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ for hashing.  I wish to add namespace to it, and added the single line as shown below.

```
<?php
namespace myNameSpace;  //I added this one line
class PasswordHash {
  //...
}
?>
```

I then create my object, however, when I apply the HashPassword method, the results are totally different.

```
require 'PasswordHash.php';
//$t_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE); //Original line
$t_hasher = new myNameSpace\PasswordHash(8, FALSE);

$correct = 'test12345';
$hash = $t_hasher->HashPassword($correct);
```

The only changes were the two lines where I added the namespace to the class and were I initiated the object.

What could cause the differences and how can identify and fix them?

Comment: please post what your output IS, and what you EXPECT it to be. From your question I can't guess "what the differences are"... since all you provide us with it "the results are totally different"...

Comment: @Tularis.  I can and will post the differences.  Why would there be any differences?  What could cause differences based on namespace?

Comment: well, the fact that you suddenly assign your class to a different namespace may lead to problems where a class references a function which used to be iniside _no_ namespace, and is now suddenly in one. This would in turn cause it to function differently.

Comment: @Tularis It didn't reference any other functions.  I ended up stumbling upon the problem.  Something to keep an eye out for.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation https://www.php.net/__destruct

> As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a
> namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This
> change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes.

phpass uses a constructor with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class. Change the name to `__construct`.